# Which process uses http-proxy 8080

Tags: http-proxy

`nmap -p1-65535 localhost` gives me

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

**What is the process that is using this port.**

From `/etc/services/`:

```
http-alt    8080/tcp    webcache    # WWW caching service
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `lsof` to find out the list of processes runing on `8080`

```
lsof -i :8080
```

You can get more detail about the process throught :

```
ps -ef | grep put_the _PID_here
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do—

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep :8080
```

you'll get something like

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:8080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     12345/processname
```

The number before `processname` is the PID of the process listening on that port.

Comment: Note that on most distros `netstat` is deprecated. `sudo ss -lnp` should work just fine though

Comment: @James_pic good point -- I'm just old :)